# ¿Por qué no funciona la propiedad margin-top: 0 en mi proyecto MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc, css3

Estoy trabajando con MVC 5 y en mi Layout "_Layout.cshtml" quiero poner un header

```
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

Sin embargo, el header no aparece en el limite de la ventana sino un poco mas abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así que intente con esto:

```
<style>
    .jumbotron
    {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

y siguió sin funcionar, pero si modifico la propiedad a margin-top: 50px; o etc, si hace el cambio ¿Alguna idea del por qué?

Comment: Te fijaste que dice el padding? hace click derecho sobre el "Bienvenidos"  y anda a "Inspeccionar Elemento", a la derecha te va a mostrar el css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca tenes 2 temas importantes

1) el body tiene un margin y padding por defecto. para solucionarlo podes hacer lo siguiente con css:

```
body{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

2) Los tag h1,h2,etc tiene también un margin por defecto. También se solucion con css.

```
 .jumbotron h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Te dejo aca un codigo HTML que me funciona correctamente.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
      body{
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
      }
      .jumbotron{
        background-color: red;
      }
      .jumbotron h2{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Bienvenido</h2>
    </div>
  </header>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que puedo marcar es que el `Jumbotron` de bootstrap no de define dentro del tag `<header>` deberías estar en el `<body>`

[Bootstrap Jumbotron](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_jumbotron_header.asp)

Por otro lado ese espacio puede generarse porque por defecto la página tiene un `margin` establecido, el cual podrias quitar con css si defines

```
body {    
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: quite el jumbotron del header, deje solo el <div> y defini el margin del body, disminuyo la separacion pero sigue sin estar en el limite de la ventana

Comment: Listo, lo solucione añadiendo un padding-top: 1px; al header